# Using an external API with pubnub DSN

Tags: javascript, json, pubnub

I'm working on a co-project for college for my final year and am making a data visualization web app using stocks. I'm hoping to use PubNub to stream my data but have been reading through the documentation on how to hook up an external API in javascript for the data such as yahoo finance or openexchangerate.org. Maybe I'm just being clueless but I cant see it anywhere but is there anyway to do it? and if so being pointed in the right direction to an example or documentation on it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Data Feed Use Case

High level steps to implement this:

1. get the data from the data feed service (not PubNub) on your server. You will need to register for an account for that service (Twitter feed, stock price feed, Wikipedia changes, etc).
2. publish that data to channels of your choosing using PubNub.
3. your client apps will subscribe to those channels via a UI that you create for them.

See [PubNub Realtime Data Streams Examples](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/realtime-data-streams/) for more details.

Let me know where you get stuck and need more details.